# Database Connection from another class

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have created a class in my program to handle database connection. This class includes a method named `OpenConnection()` to open the connection to the database. I'm not convinced that my program meets the standard of clean code. Here is the method.

```
public void OpenConnection()
{
  if(connection==null || connection.State != Connection.Open)
  {
     connection = new OracleConnection(this.connectionString);
     connection.Open();
  }
}
```

This method works okay but I just want to make sure if this is a safe way and I am not exploiting my program in any way. Thank You in advance

**Update**

I also added the following methods in the class to close the connection and dispose it.

```
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (dbconnect != null | dbconnect.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            dbconnect.Close();
        }
    }

    //Here the IDsiposable method is implemented
    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: @Igor I have update my question with the remaining methods I have declared in my class. could look at it now and tell me if this is okay. I am using the dispose method to close the SqlConnection (OracleConnection) instances right?

Comment: @Igor will you kindly suggest me an improvement? thanks

Comment: @Igor I did not understand your solution in the  3rd comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a possible resource leak owing to the fact that OracleConnection implements IDisposable.  Also, calling close on a connection in ConnectionState.Executing or Fetching could be bad as it will rollback all uncommitted transactions.

```
public void OpenConnection()
{
  if (connection == null)
  {
     connection = new OracleConnection(this.connectionString);
     connection.Open();
     return;
  }

  switch (connection.State)
  {
     case ConnectionState.Closed:
     case ConnectionState.Broken:
       connection.Close();
       connection.Dispose();
       connection = new OracleConnection(this.connectionString);
       connection.Open();
       return;
  }
}
```

Comment: so there is no need for `CloseConnection()` and `Dispose()` methods?

Comment: You added those after my answer ;)  You may want to prevent closing a connection that is in Executing state, but personally I've never needed one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use using clause and it's going to handle the Dispose automatically.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateEmployeeTable", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", 123));
    command.CommandTimeout = 5;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution as coded seems ok if you add the cases suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988829/64348) and **if it's meant to be used on a single thread and within a very limited scope**. That said it appears like you are gearing up to use this class as a parameter across many method calls because you want to

- mix business logic and persistence concerns
- or share an instance in such a way that other methods don't have to be concerned about whether to open the connection (e.g. a higher call in the call stack has not yet called `Open`) or not (e.g. a prior call in the call stack *did* open the connection (what we'd call an "ambient" connection)).

Either of these strategies usually leads to trouble. It's better to keep the scope small, where you know the connection is open and when to close it:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
}
```

When you have this small scope, your abstraction now provides no value.